# How can I safely use setTimout in combination with refs inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following hook inside a function component.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMinimized) {
      // When minimizing, delay swapping the element to the minimized node.
      // This gives the video takeover minimize animation time to run and results
      // in a more seamless looking video swap
      if (videoMinimizedRef.current !== null) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setOuterContainer(minimizedVideoRef.current);
        }, VIDEO_OVERLAY_VIDEO_ELEMENT_SWAP_TIMEOUT);
      }
    } else {
      // When maximizing, immediately swap the video element to the maximized
      // node. This ensures the video element is present at the start of the animation.
      if (videoMaximizedCallbackRef !== null) {
        setOuterContainer(videoMaximizedCallbackRef);
      }
    }
  }, [isMinimized, setOuterContainer, videoMinimizedRef, videoMaximizedCallbackRef]);
```

`isMinimized, setOuterContainer, videoMinimizedRef` are all props passed to the component.

- `isMinimized` is a boolean
- `setOuterContainer` is a useState setter function that receives an HTMLElement and sets it as the new parent node of the video element that is playing.
- `videoMinimizedRef` is a ref to the container of the video when playing minimized.

`videoMaximizedCallbackRef` is a callback ref (doesn't have `.current`) that is set in this component.

The hook works as is and does exactly what I want. That said I realize this hook has some problems (at least it seems that way from reading React hooks docs and FAQs). There is no cleanup of the setTimeout for example. That could be added like so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;
    if (isMinimized) {
      // When minimizing, delay swapping the element to the minimized node.
      // This gives the video takeover minimize animation time to run and results
      // in a more seamless looking video swap
      if (videoMinimizedRef.current !== null) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          setOuterContainer(minimizedVideoRef.current);
        }, VIDEO_OVERLAY_VIDEO_ELEMENT_SWAP_TIMEOUT);
      }
    } else {
      // When maximizing, immediately swap the video element to the maximized
      // node. This ensures the video element is present at the start of the maximize animation.
      if (videoMaximizedCallbackRef !== null) {
        setOuterContainer(videoMaximizedCallbackRef);
      }
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [isMinimized, setOuterContainer, videoMinimizedRef, videoMaximizedCallbackRef]);
```

But adding that would cause the timeout to be cleared every time any of the dependencies change. I need to make sure the timeout is never cleared when it has been started because it would cause the video swap to happen after not exactly

`VIDEO_OVERLAY_VIDEO_ELEMENT_SWAP_TIMEOUT` ms but rather

`VIDEO_OVERLAY_VIDEO_ELEMENT_SWAP_TIMEOUT + sum of time passed in previous cleared setTimeouts` ms

How can I write this hook in a way that voids the pitfalls of stale closures, and unwanted `clearTimeout` calls?

I want to adhere to the rules of hooks and exhaustive dependencies but this is a bit too much for me.

Comment: Shouldn't you also check inside the delayed function whether the component has been unmounted before changing state?

Comment: Yeah I guess? Because videoMinimizedRef.current could be null at the time of execution of the timeout since regular react refs (as opposed to callback refs) can mutated the value inside freely and it won't get stale inside hooks? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing will work just fine. When setting intervals, this isn't the right approach but for timeout it works like a charm.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let timeout;
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // set timeout callback, write your code here
  }, 100)

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }
}, [yourDependencies])
```

You can read more from dan abramov's blog: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: This doest work for me because the hook renders twice `isMinimized` and `videoMaximizedNode` props update (isMinimized goes from true to false, videoMaximizedNode goes from null to HTMLDivElement). I don't want to clear the timeout once because then the video node is moved too late and doesnt appear during the animation. I've observed this locally

Comment: You should move that to another useEffect then. I hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an event that has a timeout but you can also clear that event, it indicates that the use needs to be looking at using

The interval Timer is set once and repeats at the interval

```
tRef = setInterval(theFuncCall,timeMills)
```

and to clear

```
clearInterval( tRef );
```

If you are looking at calling intervals of 100 ms, then you should be using `setInterval` as the option for control of timings.